# Konva - Unable to completely destroy stage in react when unmounting component

Tags: reactjs, dom, konvajs, konvajs-reactjs, react-konva

I am using the Konva API directly in my react componen, and it works perfectly.

I only have one big problem.

The problem is that when the component that contains the ref container is unmounted the react app crashes, saying that staging has no container anymore.

I have tried to call destroy on the stage when the component unmounts, it enters that method but it still crashes.

So basically, from what i understand, calling destroy on stage from within the react component does not destroy the stage from the DOM.

Could anyone help with this issue?

EDIT: adding code snippet

```
    export default class ReactComp extends Component {
     renderKonva(container) {

     var stage = new Konva.Stage({
       container: container,
       width: 500, 
       height: 350
     });
     var layer = new Konva.Layer();
     var rect = new Konva.Rect({
      stroke: '#155DA4',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      fill: '#fff',
      width: 190,
      height: 190,
      shadowColor: 'black',
      shadowBlur: 10,
      shadowOffset: [10, 10],
      shadowOpacity: 0.2,
      cornerRadius: 2,
      opacity: 0.75,
      visible: true
     });
     layer.add(rect);
     stage.add(layer);
    }

    render() {
      return (
       <div ref={ref => this.renderKonva(ref)}></div>
      )
    }
```

So whenever this component unmounts i get the error:
"Uncaught Stage has no container. A container is required."

Also, i have tried calling destroy on the stage, but i still get the same error. Also, even if i create and destroy the stage in renderKonva, and in essence i will have nothing displayed, because stage was once created it throws the same error.

Comment: Please see creating a [mcve], so we can see your issue and reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry, we need to see your code to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, i have added some code, hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderKonva` is a [callbackRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs). From the docs:

> React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and call it with null when it unmounts.

That means, when it unmounts `container` is `undefined`.

So,

```
export default class ReactComp extends Component { 
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.stage = null;
 }

 renderKonva(container) {
  if (!container) {
    this.stage.destroy();
    return;
  }

  var stage = new Konva.Stage({
   container: container,
   width: 500,
   height: 350
  });

  this.stage = stage;
  ...
 }
```

}